# Doubts on the properties of the set of the integers.

Tags: general-topology

We have the set S: $\Bbb Z^2$ in $\Bbb R^2$

Which I have learnt in class that have the following properties:

$\Bbb R^2\setminus\Bbb Z^2$ is open, hence $\Bbb Z^2$ is closed.

$\operatorname{Int}(S)≠∅$

$bd(S)=S$

$cl(S)=S$

I understand why $\Bbb Z^2$ is closed, but I don't understand the last properties.

Comment: What do you denote $bd$ and $cl$?

Comment: @Bernard boundary and closure

Comment: The closure of a closed set is itself, by definition. The interior of $\mathbb Z^2$ is empty, since it is a countable set. The boundary of a set is the closure minus the interior.

Comment: There are standard notations for that: $\operatorname{Fr}(S)$ and  $\overline{S}$. Also, what is denoted by $S$ is not clear to me.

Comment: @Bernard I have never seen the notation $Fr(S)$, only $bd(S)$ and $\partial S$.

Comment: @Bernard Those are far less standard than bd and cl... (Okay maybe not $\overline S$ but Fr$(S)$ is certainly much less used than bd).

Comment: This notation exists in Bourbaki's treatise. It comes from the other name of the boundary – the *frontier* of $S$.

Comment: Imagine that $S$ is just a single point in $\Bbb R$: in this case $S$ has the same properties described in your question. If you understand the single point case, you should understand also your case.

Comment: @Bernard I'm aware. One author doesn't make it more common. bd is far more common.

Comment: @DonThousand: bd  is only natural in english.

Comment: @Bernard Well, luckily for us, we are on an English speaking platform. I don't use "seema" as boundary even though it is quite common in some non-English mathematical conventions.